# Awesome WM: How can I iterate through all clients in all tags?

Tags: awesome-wm

modkey+j or modkey+k only cycles between clients in the same tag.
How can I cycle through all clients disregarding the tag they are? Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

There is no such function built-in, but the following might work (untested):

```
function next_client_total(i)
  local c = client.focus
  if not c then return end
  local cls = client.get()
  local fcls = {}
  -- Remove all non-normal clients
  for _, c in ipairs(cls) do
    if awful.client.focus.filter(c) or c == sel then
      table.insert(fcls, c)
    end
  end
  -- Find the focused client
  for idx, c in ipairs(fcls) do
    if c == sel then
      -- Found it, focus and raise the "target"
      local c = fcls[awful.util.cycle(#fcls, idx + i)]
      client.focus = c
      c:raise()
      return
    end
  end
end
```

Then, add keybindings like this:

```
awful.key({ modkey }, "j", function() next_client_total(1) end)
awful.key({ modkey }, "k", function() next_client_total(-1) end)
```